# Почему не работает форма в Django?

Tags: django

```
При нажатии на кнопку "Опубликовать историю", просто обновляется история и всё. Статья не добавляется.





    URLS:
                    app_name = 'history'
                urlpatterns = [
                        ...
                        path('to_write/', views.post_new ,name = 'to_write'),

                ]
        FORMS:
        from django import forms
        from .models import History
        class PostHistory(forms.ModelForm):
            class Meta:
                model = History
                fields = ['history_title', 'history_text']

        MODELS:
        from django.db import models

        class History(models.Model):
            history_title = models.CharField('Название вашей ситории', max_length = 75)
            history_text = models.TextField('Текст истории')
            pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации')

    VIEWS:
    def post_new(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PostHistory(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.save()
                return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
        else:
            form = PostHistory()
        return render(request, 'history/list.html', {'form': form})

LISR.HTML:
{% block content %} 
<h1>Новая история!</h1>
<form action="{% url 'history:to_write' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}

<input type="text" required="" placeholder="Введите название истории!" name="name"><br>
<textarea name="text" required="" placeholder="Текст истории" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
<button type="submit">Опубликовать историю!</button>
</form> 
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: вам обязательно с классом ModelForm? можете вообще без файла forms.py. Просто получаете POST данные со страницы

Comment: Ну она не работает потому что вы сохраняете во views форму но не выходите ее

Comment: а как нужно,чтобы работао?

Comment: @jadesheart добавил

Answer (score 1):

в шаблоне html

```
{% block content %} 
      <h1>Новая история!</h1>
<form action="" method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{form}}
   <button type="submit">Опубликовать историю!</button>
</form> 
{% endblock %}
```